# corrupted keys file in chef vault

Tags: chef-infra, chef-vault

Today I saw that all my chef-clients fail to run their recipes becaue they can't decrypt our ssh keys vault.

I tried to show my vault and got the following:

```
knife vault show secrets ssh_keys
ERROR: Chef::Exceptions::JSON::ParseError: parse error: premature EOF
                                   {"id":"ssh_keys_keys","admins":
                 (right here) ------^
```

then I tried to show the data bag of the vault:

```
knife data bag show secrets ssh_keys
```

this command showed my encrypted data but when I tried to show the keys item I got the same error as before:

```
knife data bag show secrets ssh_keys_keys
ERROR: Chef::Exceptions::JSON::ParseError: parse error: premature EOF
                                   {"id":"ssh_keys_keys","admins":
                 (right here) ------^
```

Chef Version: 12.14.89
Vault Version: 2.9.0

1) can I see last changes to a vault in chef so I know what cause it?
2) does anyone have a solution how to fix this keys item?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem with my chef-server.
Chef server was out of disk space and after removing some log files the problem solved

Comment: Good. Glad to hear the problem solved and thanks for sharing. Could you please click the button and accept your own answer so people will know that problem was solved?

Comment: Sure, I just didn't know about this feature.
I don't ask a lot